# Ansible playbook treating pythonpath as a directory or file

Tags: ansible

```
 - name: Migrate graphite settings
   command: 
     argv:
       - PYTHONPATH=/opt/graphite/webapp/ 
       - django-admin 
       - migrate 
       - --settings=graphite.settings
   ignore_errors: yes
```

Is producing:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "PYTHONPATH=/opt/graphite/webapp/ django-admin migrate --settings=graphite.settings", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'PYTHONPATH=/opt/graphite/webapp/'", "rc": 2}
```

I think Ansible is reading PYTHONPATH as a file or directory. Which it isn't. How can I get a command to treat PYTHONPATH= as just setting the PYTHONPATH value for a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, one more ansible-y than the other:

The ansible way is `environment:` as in

```yaml
 - name: Migrate graphite settings
   environment:
     PYTHONPATH: /opt/graphite/webapp/
   command: 
     argv:
       - django-admin 
       - migrate 
       - --settings=graphite.settings
   ignore_errors: yes
```

and the other is to use the [`env`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/env.1.html) *command* such that becomes something that can be executed; that `SOME_VAR=some-value some_command` syntax is a shell construct, and thus can only be used with `shell:` or by explicitly wrapping argv in a `[sh, -c]` which would defeat the purpose of `command:`

```yaml
 - name: Migrate graphite settings
   command: 
     argv:
       - env
       - PYTHONPATH=/opt/graphite/webapp/ 
       - django-admin 
       - migrate 
       - --settings=graphite.settings
   ignore_errors: yes
```